# Cannot add path to package

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-apps

I have download django-todo for my website, I am writting some function on the view but i am not able to add path to the urls.py even if it is correct.

For example :

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import path
from todo import views
from todo.features import HAS_TASK_MERGE

app_name = "todo"

path("add_list/", views.add_list, name="add_list"),
path("add_listreccurence/", views.add_listreccurence, name="add_listreccurence"),
```

The first one come with the package, the second is mine. 
It is exactly on the same file, with the same path but I cannot import it, it says :

`AttributeError: module 'todo.views' has no attribute 'add_listreccurence'`

Could you help me ?

Thanks

Edit :

for example :

```
 @login_required
def add_list(request) -> HttpResponse:
    """Allow users to add a new todo list to the group they're in.
    """


    if request.POST:
        form = AddTaskListForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
```

And mine just below

```
@login_required
    def add_listreccurence(request) -> HttpResponse:
        """Allow users to add a new todo list to the group they're in.
        """


        if request.POST:
            form = AddTaskListForm(request.user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
```

I added some different parameters below but still, they are on the same file, using the same urls.py inside the same app...

Comment: the `todo` you said is your module?  so views is your code.  So, you haven't made a `add_listreccurence` function, but you are trying to run it. Am I not understanding something correctly?

Comment: No, the add_listreccurence is a view on the same views.py that add list.

Comment: can you perhaps provide that code as well.

Comment: i added some details